# jQuery function .split() not working, AJAX data not submitted

Tags: jquery, ajax

This first section of code of the two following works. The data is properly transferred to the php.

Please pay attention to the `'topost':'momo_1'` under `data` of the ajax request:

```
var linkwjpg = $("#blurpost").attr("src").split("/").pop().split(".", 1);
$("h1").text(linkwjpg);
var myInterval = setInterval(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'time.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {'user':'<?php echo $_SESSION["login"] ?>','topost':'momo_1'},
        success: function() {

        }
    });
}, 1000);
```

If I replace " 'momo_1' " with "linkwjpg", which is in my case 'momo_1', it suddenly won't work anymore...

```
var linkwjpg = $("#blurpost").attr("src").split("/").pop().split(".", 1);
$("h1").text(linkwjpg);
var myInterval = setInterval(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'time.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {'user':'<?php echo $_SESSION["login"] ?>','topost':linkwjpg},
        success: function() {

        }
    });
}, 1000);
```

Can anyone help me?
I've been working on that for an entire day now and still can't figure out what's the problem...

Comment: try `data: JSON.stringify({user:<?php echo $_SESSION["login"] ?>,topost:linkwjpg})`

Comment: `linkwjpg` is an array and not a string

Comment: and ofcourse, as per @Andreas' comment, make sure you send a string and not an array. as of now, `linkwjpg` actually contains `["momo_1"]`. do `linkwjpg=linkwjpg[0]`

Comment: Thank you both so much!! It's working! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.split()` always returns an array. Therefor `linkwjpg` is not only the string `"momo_1"` but an array containing the string `["momo_1"]`

And because of the way jQuery handles an array ([this](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/serialize.js#L55) and [this](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/serialize.js#L15)) found in the `data` property the `topost` property will be submitted as

```
topost%5B%5D=momo_1  // topost[]=momo_1 (https://jsfiddle.net/5k6jtew2/)
```

---

A possible solution would be:

```
var linkwjpg = $("#blurpost").attr("src").split("/").pop().split(".", 1)[0];
```

or

```
data: {'user':'<?php echo $_SESSION["login"] ?>','topost':linkwjpg[0]}
```

Answer (score -2):

if `linkwjpg` is an array, I think you must fix this this line `$("h1").text(linkwjpg);`

Comment: sorry, i forgot to say i used this to test if the variable says "momo_1". So that works, it's "momo_1"...